# c# drawing objects at once instead of using a loop

Tags: c#, performance, loops, animation, graphics

Hello i am trying to draw about 1000 images and between 10 to 100 rectangels and elipses.
But i need all of them to show up on screen only when they done loading(not in a loading screen but in a game or slideshow). so for example

```
texturegrass = MyApp.Properties.Resources.Grass
Rectangle[] rects;
recs = new Rectangle[1000]
for (int i = 0; i < rects.Length; i++)
        {
            g.DrawImage(texturegrass,rects[i]);
        }
```

this is what i done so far but every rectangle is been drawn by it own what cause a flickering problam.

I have double bufferd the app.
I tried using parallel but the application keep crashing

I hope one of you guys can help me...

---

##*

Comment: even if you manage to add it to a memoryStream which seems as your best choice, you would still have to draw them byte by byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Graphics` object to create the image off-screen, and then draw the image on the screen using the screen's `Graphics` object.

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(MyWidth, CMyHeight);
var gOff = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
gOff.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.White), 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
texturegrass = MyApp.Properties.Resources.Grass
Rectangle[] rects = ...;
recs = new Rectangle[1000]
for (int i = 0; i < rects.Length; i++) {
    gOff.DrawImage(texturegrass,rects[i]);
}
```

At this point you can draw `bmp` all at once on the screen's `Graphic`.

[Microsoft: How to Draw Images Off-Screen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172506%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: It worked but when i put it in animation it filckers even more

Comment: @user2183919 For animation you should render your frames ahead of time, store them in an array, and use pre-rendered images for flicker-free animation.

Comment: How can I pre render images?

Comment: @user2183919 Use the code that draws off-screen for each frame of your animation, and store each bitmap separately in a collection of frame images.

Comment: Can I still use that method?
because what I done with it is to draw the background, but it didn't worked that well, even so when I tested it on an all ready made animation it worked great and very fast.
so can I make any modafication for a game?
That would be great and will probbaly slove my problam.

Comment: Yes, it's called double buffering. You paint your next frame in a bitmap offscreen, and when the painting is done you flip the onscreen bitmap with the offscreen bitmap.